# How do I invoke GhostScript

Tags: ghostscript

I am familiar with Windows convention exe or com, but I just installed GhostScrirpt and find nothing that seems like it would invoke GhostScript. Ultimately, I am trying to use GSView. Please respond to neilhmurphy at outlook.com.

Comment: If you used the Artifex-supplied Windows installer, downloaded from Ghostscript.com, then Ghostscript will be installed in your start menu. To find out where the executable is, and what its called, right click on the start menu item and select 'properties' from the context menu. GSView has not been updated for many tears and has slipped out of synchronisation with Ghostscript, it can no longer automatically find the DLL (not the executable), so you need to use advanced configure, and it no longer works at all with PDF as the input file format.